# How to remove combinations that contains same number twice from the list, which contains that same number repetitively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I want to type the code for the combinations of up-to k sub-sequences which starts from 1 to k. Here I am trying to find the sub-sequences which doesn't contain same number twice, even though list contains.

I am trying to do it, but I am failing on the first part.

```
import itertools

lst1=[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 9, 5, 1, 2]
k = int(input())
lst = [i for j in range(1,k+1) for i in itertools.combinations(lst1, j)]
set1 = set(lst)
print(lst)
print(set1)
```

The code should give answers like :
[(1,2,3), (1,3,5),...so on] but it should not give (1,2,1) or (1,2,2) because it contains repetitive number.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you be a bit more precise about your exact desired output? I'm a bit confused because your output doesn't start with an empty list followed by tuples like `(1,)`, etc. Instinctively, though, why not use `set(lst1)` and pass that into `combinations`? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for that. my list does start with 1 element in tuples and than it goes for 2 elements but when it goes for 2 elements I don't want same elements to comes in like (1, 1) and so on... and if it goes for three elements I don't want repetitive elements like (1,2,1) or (1,1,2) in any form it should not come in list. and Thank You @ggorlen

Comment: I upgraded my code a bit as you said using the sets but it is still giving repetitive elements like (1,2,2) in the list. @ggorlen

Comment: Can you post the desired output verbatim? I'm still left guessing what the precise output should be. Thanks.

Comment: If my list is [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], my output should contain... (1,2); (1,2); (1,3); (1,2); (1,2); (1,3); (2,3); (2,3); (1,2,3); (1,2,3); (1,2,3); (1,2,3) ------ Here my output neglected all the (1,1); (2,2); or (2,2,3).... And its not necessary it should be in tuples only it can be list form too. @ggorlen

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic i have write this code in order to remove duplicate list from list.

```
import itertools

lst1=[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 9, 5, 1, 2]
k = int(input())
lst = [i for j in range(1,k+1) for i in itertools.combinations(lst1, j)]
set1 = set(lst)
print(lst)
print(set1)
all_combination = list(set1)
new = []
status = False
for i in all_combination:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        l = j+1
        for k in range(l, len(i)):
            if i[j] == i[k] and i[j] not in new:
                status = True
                break
            else:
                status = False
        if status == True:
            break
    if status == False:
        new.append(i)
print(new)
```

But your sample answers shows the combination of given number of subsets having length 3 or n. and remove duplicate from it. This is my code which will return all the combination of numbers present in list with length 3 or n and remove duplicates, just change the value of `s` and you will get the combination accordingly.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 9, 5, 1, 2]
s = 3
new_list = []
all_combination = []
def combination(numbers, n, subset):
    if len(subset) == n:
        all_combination.append(subset)
    else:
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            combination(numbers, n, subset + [numbers[i]])
combination(l1, s, new_list)
print(all_combination)
unique = []
status = False
for i in all_combination:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        l = j+1
        for k in range(l, len(i)):
            if i[j] == i[k] and i[j]:
                status = True
                break
            else:
                status = False
        if status == True:
            break

    if status == False:
        unique.append(i)
print(unique)
```

[image: Output]